# SSRS: Adjust image size based on table row

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report which shows an image from the database and some text below and above it. The size of the image can vary.

At the moment I have the image in the same table as the text. I basically want that there is always the same gap between the image and the text. When I set the image size to "Fit proportional" it often uses up only a part of the cell height and leaves therefore a big gap to the text below.

What I need is the possibility to let the row height be the height of the image when the image is set to "Fit proportional".

I know about "CanGrow" and "CanShrink". But when I use a very narrow cell and have "Fit proportional" the image is of course fit to the size of the cell. Using "Original Size" has the problem that big images exceed the size of the cell.

Is there a way to do solve my problem?